# Random variable X with mean $E(X)=7$ and $var(X)=6$. Calculate $E((X-a)^2)$?

Tags: random-variables, expectation, variance

I have looked for answer long time and given hints are that mean is $E(Y)=E(ag(X)+bh(X))$ and variance for random variable X is $var(X)=E(X^2)−[E(X)]^2$. I hope someone could help me with my problem.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Please make your question legible with [**mathjax**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

1. $Var(X-a)=Var(X)$
2. $E(X-a)=E(X)-a$
3. $Var(X-a)=E((X-a)^2)-(E(X-a))^2$

Can you use these in the correct order?

Comment: I got E((X-a)^2) = Var(X-a)+(E(X-a))^2 = Var(x) +(E(X-a))^2 = 6+(7-a)^2= a^2 -14a +55. Im not sure what im doing but I solved for a and it gave me complex roots so Im still stuck with this problem. Any further advices? Im I on the right track?

Comment: @Eric That's perfect. Congrats!

Comment: sorry I sent my post too early. So, any advices? Thank you very much for your replies!

Comment: @Eric Your answer was pitch perfect, you had nothing to add after "$6+(7-a)^2$". What you have is not an equation to solve, it's an expression to find. And you found it. Conclusion, "$E((X-a)^2)=6+(7-a)^2$". Full stop.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for your time again!

Comment: @Eric You're welcome! You can upvote my answer if it was useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

$(X-a)^2 = X^2 - 2Xa + a^2\\
E[(X-a)^2] = E[X^2] - 2a E[X] + a^2\\
Var X = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$

And that should be enough to substitute what you know to find what you don't know.

Comment: There is no need to develop the square.

Comment: Do you think that it is more work to expand $(X-a)^2$ than to calculate $E[(X-a)]^2$

Comment: Yes. $(E(X-a))^2$ is $(7-a)^2$ and doesn't need to be expanded (see my post above or below).